# Shingles with lattice package's equal.count()

Tags: r, grouping, lattice

Why does the `equal.count()` function create overlapping shingles when it is clearly possible to create groupings with no overlap. Also, on what basis are the overlaps decided?

For example:

```
equal.count(1:100,4)

Data:
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22
 [23]  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44
 [45]  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66
 [67]  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88
 [89]  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100

Intervals:
   min   max count
1  0.5  40.5    40
2 20.5  60.5    40
3 40.5  80.5    40
4 60.5 100.5    40

Overlap between adjacent intervals:
[1] 20 20 20
```

Wouldn't it be better to create groups of size 25 ? Or maybe I'm missing something that makes this functionality useful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The overlap smooths transitions between the shingles (which, as the name says, overlap on the roof), but a better choice would have been to use some windowing  function such as in spectral analysis.

I believe it is a pre-historic relic, because the behavior goes back to some very old pre-lattice code and is used in `coplot` remembered only by veteRans. `lattice::equal.count` calls `co.intervals` in `graphics`, where you will find some explanation. Try:

```
lattice:::equal.count(1:100,4,overlap=0)
```

Comment: Thanks! If I could ask for another clarification...  
`> sort(environmental$temperature)  
> temp.cut<-equal.count(sort(environmental$temperature),4,overlap=0)`
  
still gives me overlapping cuts. My understanding is that this is possibly because of the fact that the data contains repeated items at the would-be boundaries. Is this correct?  

(Sorry, couldn't paste output. It exceeds the comment length)